# Set variable from awk while parsing lines from a multiline file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I've got a txt file with several lines, each one describing a remote server, like this:

```
user@server:port:remote_working_path:whether_using_VPN
```

The : char separates the 4 fields.

I need to operate batch actions within each server, hence I need to parse each line and set appropriate variables. Right now, what I've coded is this:

```
while read server;
do
        echo "$server" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' &&
        echo "$server" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' &&
        echo "$server" | awk -F ':' '{print $3}'
        echo "$VPN"
        declare $( echo "$server" | awk -F ':' '{print $VPN=$4}' )
        echo 'VPN: '$VPN
done < $CUSTOMER_SERVERS_FILE
```

This script only prints the first 3 fields, and in my intentions should also set $VPN variable as the 4th field. However this seems way broken, and I'm being unable to fix it. How should I modify it so that $VPN = $4?

Comment: Why not just `tr ':' $'\n' < $file` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl : I don't really understand the connection with the OP's question.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann Basically the OP is just outputting each field on a new line. Isn't it?

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't think so (see my answer).

Comment: I saw it already, and it makes sense. However, the example in the question makes no sense then.

Comment: @hek2mgl The echoes in my initial script were just for testing purposes. Perhaps I should have stated it more explicitly, sorry if it caused confusion.

Comment: No problem. I though I can help out with a simple command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you don't need to use `awk` in this case. You could try to use something like :

```
while IFS=':' read -ra array; do 
    # "${array[0]}" => first field
    # "${array[1]}" => second field
    # ...
    # "${array[@]}" => all fields    
done < "$CUSTOMER_SERVERS_FILE"
```

Then if you want to set VPN variable with the 4th field, you could use :

```
while IFS=':' read -ra array; do 
    # ...
    VPN="${array[3]}"
done < "$CUSTOMER_SERVERS_FILE"
```

Another solution :

```
while IFS=':' read -r address port path vpn trash; do
    # The variables $adress $port $path and $vpn are assigned.
    # $trash is set with other fields if there are more than 4 fields
done
```

Finally, when you want to assign the output of a command in a variable, you could do :

```
var="$(command)"
# or
var="`command`"
```

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you so much, very clean and simple solution. Hopefully I'll learn how to decently code bash scripts someday!

Comment: @Seether I'm glad to help you. Don't hesitate to consult the advanced "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide" if you want to improve your bash scripting level : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: +1: Though I wouldn't recommend the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide. I would rather point to [Bash Guide](http://folk.ntnu.no/geirha/bashguide.pdf) by lhunath.

Comment: I also have a good full course easier to start shell POSIX and bash programming but unfortunately in French ^^. @jaypal thanks for sharing this link.

Comment: If you are going to assign each element of the array to a separate variable in the body of the loop, let `read` do the assignment for you: `IFS=: read -r address port path vpn`.

Comment: @chepner: I also wanted to offer this solution but I'm not sure on how many fields are on this file. However, I'll write an alternative.